# How to fix sqlsrv in info.php?

Tags: php, iis-7.5, sqlsrv

I am using

Ultimate goal: To install wordpress in IIS with MSSQL as DB backend (sqlsrvmethod)

Primary Objective: info.php doesn't shows, "slqsrv".

So trying to install that extension or directive into php. Configuration as below,

1. Web server - IIS,
2. mssql driver 3.0,
3. sqlsrv NOT PDO,
4. PHP version 5.4.3 (PHP-CGI.exe is being used from D: loaded which is present in wamp/bin/php/php.5.4.3. Since couldn't get any php-cgi.exe along with php file from php.net)
5. MSSQL 2008
6. Thread Safety - Enabled, can't able to download php_sqlsrv_54_nts.dll or php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_nts.dll.
7. Ended up with below, PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'D:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\ext\php_sqlsrv_53_ts.dll' - The specified module could not be found.

Comment: The php_sqlsrv_54_nts.dll or php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_nts.dll got from the sql server driver for php and loaded into PHP root folder. While I tried to run->cmd->regsvr32 path/php_sqlsrv_54_nts.dll or php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll, there are 2 different errors. 1. error - compatible with 82x(32bit) or 64x(32bit) and 2. Is a valide DLL or OCX file or not.

Comment: [11-Oct-2013 13:33:35 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\php\php\php5.3.13\ext\php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_nts.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
 in Unknown on line 0
 
[11-Oct-2013 13:33:35 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\php\php\php5.3.13\ext\php_curl.dll' - The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail.
 in Unknown on line 0

The above are the 2 errors that I ended up with after trying so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The php must be installed in the default location of C: drive. Then point it in IIS using PHP manager.
2. The SQLSRV.v.3.0 must be installed in default location C:

These helped me to resolve the issue easier.

Answer (score 0):

First you must have:

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll
```

in your php.ini file, and both above mentioned drivers must be in "ext" folder of php and you must restart your apache or iis server, then it should show as you expected.....

Comment: you failed to read my comments Oct 11 at 4:43 and  Oct 11 at 13:50